# An easy question about NP-hard

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity, np-complete

Consider an optimization problem includes two variables. If we fix the value of one variable, then the optimization problem over the other variable is NP-hard. Can it be concluded that the original problem over two variables is always NP-hard?

Comment: You're indeed using the reduction argument i.e. two-variables is reducible to one-variable problem, or in other words, two-variables problem is at least as hard as one-variable problem so is NP-hard. Put it differently, if you can solve the two-variables problem efficiently, then you can also solve one-variable problem efficiently by fixing one variable, of course.

Comment: I'm not really sure what are you asking about, but here is an example to think about: take a problem of [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), with the constraint that  all the inputs are integral and the solution times $c$ (that it, $x_i\cdot c$ for all $i$) has to be integral, where the constant $c$ is a part of the solution. If $c$ is fixed, then this is hard, but if you can set $c$, this problem becomes solvable (the optimal, non-integral solution is a vector of rational numbers $x_i=p_i/q_i$, so it's enough to put $c=\prod_i q_i$).

Comment: When you say "If we fix the value of one variable, then the optimization problem over the other variable is NP-hard.", is that true for *every* value you fix the variable to, or only for some values, i.e. in the worst case?

Comment: for every value

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot be concluded. What you are describing is not a strict restriction of the problem. I will give a counter example.

Suppose you have a problem $A$ that takes an input $n$ that characterizes a two variable function $f$, and that outputs $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)$ is of maximal value. Further suppose that a problem $B_c$ does the same thing for a constant $c$ in the range of $f$'s first input, except it outputs $y$ that maximizes $f(c,y)$. Finally, suppose that $B_c$ is NP-hard. This is the context of the question as I understand it from the post and a clarification in comments.

Now, suppose $f$ as characterized by the input $n$ is maximal at $(n,n)$. Then $A$ is a constant time problem.

It is not inconsistent to also suppose, fixing $c$, that any NP problem with input $m$ is equivalent to some problem $B_c$ with input $m^\prime$ for some $m^\prime$. Sure, if $m^\prime$ happens to equal $c$, then that special case is constant time. However, this need not be the case, and then the universally optimal $(m^\prime,m^\prime)$ is irrelevant, as it is not a valid response for an algorithm solving $B_c$.

Thus any NP-problem can be reduced to $B_c$ for any $c$, and so all $B_c$ are NP-hard.

Comment: This would be convincing with a real counterexample, rather than *supposing* without proof $B_c$ is NP-hard, because on the face of it $B_c$ looks no harder to optimize than $A$.

Comment: Its not supposed to be a proof, just an argument as to why you cannot take for granted the proposed conclusion. And it is absolutely satisfying for that purpose. Additionally, it would be easy to construct an example, as the optimal for (n,n) condition can be imposed by modifying any real example by setting those values to some value above any other ever attained by the functions; changing that one value per function is basically all it would take to get an example, given a case where $A$ is NP-hard.

Comment: Also, the $B_c$ is not just assumed to be NP-hard, that is part of the condition given in the problem. OP is saying that fixing one variable produces an NP-hard problem. $B_c$ is $A$ with one variable fixed.